# Why is Lattice QCD done in Euclidian 4-space?

Tags: yang-mills, lattice-gauge-theory

This could be a really naive question (and honestly I just don't want to dig through ArXiV review papers on lattice QCD), but my question is simple:

**Why exactly is Lattice QCD done in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and not Minkowski space?**.

I'm a physics graduate student, so answers on this this level are preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Minkowski space, you will have an oscillating factor $\exp(iS_M)$ in the path integral. This is difficult to deal with numerically. It is often called the 'sign problem.' In Euclidean space you have a real exponential $\exp(-S_E)$ which you can deal with using things like the Metropolis algorithm. Even in Euclidean space there can be imaginary terms in the action arising from things like the vacuum angle, and these need special methods to treat.

Comment: At finite chemical potential $\mu$ this method does not help any more, the Wick rotation will make it an imaginary chemical potential and you are back to square one. Simulations are therefore done with $\mu = 0$ or an imaginary chemical potential. There are new methods being explored like the *Lefschetz thimbles*.

Comment: @MartinUeding, Yes I have read some interesting papers on that. That's what I was getting at in my last sentence